# Writing variables to the next available spreadsheet row in a Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Quick question:  I am a newbie to Google Apps Script, and want to do something really simple.  I have a spreadsheet where I would like to log my results every time the script runs.  Let's say I have three variables, and each time I execute, I want to go to the first available empty row in the sheet, and assign variable #1 to Column A, variable #2 to Column B, etc.  I'm guessing there's all types of examples where that kind of thing happens every day. Can someone point me to such an example?

Thanks for your help.

TomC

Answer (score 3):

maybe this way is better or at least shorter:

```
var logSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(logSpreadsheetId).getSheets()[0];
logSheet.appendRow([var1, var2, var3]);
```

Comment: `appendRow` is the best solution because it's atomic. It either executes successfully or it fails, compared to getting the last row and then manually writing to a new one, where you can have intervening mutations by mistake.

Answer (score 2):

In your Google Apps Script, you will want to look at something called sheet.getLastRow()

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 // This logs the value in the very last cell of this sheet
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
 var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
 var lastCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow, lastColumn);
 Logger.log(lastCell.getValue());
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow()